# JSXGraph - Move point along with label

Tags: jsxgraph

Is it possible to move point while dragging its label ?
In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radhe/c28bpzLq/) while dragging the point, its label moves along.

```
    var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jsxgbox', { axis: true});

    var p1 = board.create('point', [-3,-1], {name: "Drag Me",label:{fixed:false}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, it is not possible to move a point by dragging it's label. An alternative approach is to create a point without label and a separate text element containing the label text. Then put both elements in a group:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jsxgbox', {
    axis: true
});

var p1 = board.create('point', [-3,-1], {name: "", label:{visible:false}});
var t1 = board.create('text', [-2.8, -0.8, "Drag me"]);
var g1 = board.create('group', [p1, t1]);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/c28bpzLq/4/ for an example.

Comment: This is cool Alfred. Thanks ! So the 'text' element is now a part of group!

Comment: The position of the three element classes `point`, `text`, `image` is determined by a coordinate vector. For this, we interoduced the new element `CoordsElement`. Gradually we try to achieve that these three classes are treated identically. For groups this already has been achieved.